# hg Mercurial repo size / file size / file size in commits

Tags: mercurial, repository, tortoisehg

1) How to get the list of files with their sizes of some commit through command line like this:

```
hg files --template "{name} {length}\n"
```

2) How to get the size of Mercurial through command line like this:

```
hg size my_directory
```

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there's no straight forward way without any external utilities.

Make use of the appropriate OS utilities, answering both of your question at once (should work on *nix and OSX):

```
hg files -rXXX | xargs du -h
```

Comment: 'du' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. - What should I download else?

Comment: This should have been `| xargs du -h`, although I don't feel this answers the question satisfactorily.

Comment: @Ringding I know of no internal facility to achieve the question - and I don't see the need to add that functionality to mercurial itself, given the ease to achieve that as I demonstrated; thanks for the hint wrt xargs. Without it also lists the files in the .hg dir which is unwanted. I'll correct my answer accordingly

Comment: @Ringding thanks! but it's not working on Windows 10. In the Linux it works perfectly.

Comment: @planetmaker I want something like this: hg files : --template {filepath} {size} {flag} {insertions_count} {deletions_count}. Is it possible?

Comment: As stated above: I don't see that as a one-line hg command. All I could work out would work on linux or OSX only. For windows you'll have to use its command line facilities which I'm not familiar with.

Comment: @planetmaker can I get number of insertions as a digit ? hg log --stat gives me insertions as a sequence of '+' and '-'

Comment: Read properly the output. As the last line of output it gives you both as numbers...  `1 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)`

Comment: @planetmaker yes , I know about it. It gives me a sum of insertions for all files. And I don’t know a command that give insertions and deletions count for each file separately

Comment: @Ringding should I sum files sizes to get a size of my repo? Or is there one command that gives me a repo size

Answer (score 0):

To report information about the size of a particular file as of a particular revision, you can use the pattern:

```
hg cat --rev REV FILE | wc -c
```

Generalizing this a bit, if REV is a specific revision of interest, we could obtain a listing of filenames and file sizes by writing:

```
hg files --rev $REV . |
  while read -r f ; do 
    echo $f $(hg cat --rev $REV "$f" | wc -c)
  done
```